# youtube api getting started node error

Tags: node.js, api, youtube

I'm following along with the youtube docs getting started with node.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs I have the client_secret.json in the working directory file downloaded however I'm getting this error when launching

```
>
mason@lubuntu:~/Desktop/chentabot$ node quickstart.js
undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /home/mason/Desktop/chentabot/quickstart.js:42:39
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:447:3)
```

line 42 refers to this section of the code

```
// Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
```

and it seems that it's using the json file called youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json when its defined earlier on the sample.  I can not however find this file or the path its located on my system.

```
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';
```

Any idea on how to proceed?  I ultimately want to be able to use this api to update and remove videos on a public youtube playlist.

Answer (score 0):

File and ./credentials ended up being hidden